# downhole chart - recharts or chart.js or anything else?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, recharts

good day, a non typical question, please don't bite.

I am using a react library.
I need to implement a downhole plot chart and typically, for charts, I use recharts library (https://recharts.org/en-US/).
But I never met such graphs that our designer implemented and I don't want to waste time if it is not possible with recharts.

[image]

So, the question is: what free library can be used to make such graphs? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is no answers but some minus from someone resentful without comment, so typical.

I dared to did that with recharts's vertical line chart, so I hope it helps anyone